# byte array in java returning null after conversion from objects

Tags: java, android, serialization, javabeans

I need to send my phone contacts in android as bytes. So i have crated a bean class implementing serializable , but after converting the arraylist of bean class to byte array, byte array is  always showing null. Here is my sample code.

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
 oos.writeObject(presentContacts);
 byte[] buf = baos.toByteArray();
```

Here presentContacts is the ArrayList of bean class. Byte array, buf is always returning null but presentContacts is not null.

Comment: Are you saying the call to `toByteArray()` produced `null`?

Comment: yes, toByteArray() is producing null.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't any Exceptions? Perhaps a non-serializable field of your bean class? Looking at the source of ByteArrayOutputStream, it doesn't seem possible for it to return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably  close or at least flush the `ObjectOutputStream`. 
Something like this

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
 oos.writeObject(presentContacts);
 oos.flush(); 
 byte[] buf = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Try to close ObjectOutputStream instead flush

Comment: Maybe error occured while serialization (check your bean is serializable)

Comment: Each time, i write to OutputStream, i got following warning in logcat
WARN/AudioFlinger(72): write blocked for 91 msecs, 86 delayed writes, thread 0xdf38
Does it mean anything while writing to stream, i dont know this error.

Comment: How you check byte[] buf is null or not ? Maybe you need put breakpoint after byte[] buf = baos.toByteArray(); try just call System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buf)); as offer @RayToal ; Flushing is  working exactly

Comment: flush worked for conversion, but while converting  bytes back to arraylist sometimes worked, sometimes not .thankx for the help..